# What's the difference between JQueryMobile form text inputs?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to familiarize myself with JQuery mobile forms so I can work with them more extensively in the future, however something has come up that is baffling me. The JQuery mobile API doesn't explain it as far as I could tell, and I'm kind of at a loss.

My problem is that when trying to create different text inputs for things such as email and telephone number, for example, the resulting input area looks exactly the same.

For Example:

```
<input type="email" data-clear-btn="true" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
<input type="tel" data-clear-btn="true" name="number" id="number" placeholder="Phone Number">
```

What is the difference between these two text fields? Is it in how they're validated when the form is submitted?

Comment: If you are talking about a jQuery plug-in you should mention which one.

Comment: Not a plugin. Trying to avoid those.

Comment: Looking at the "data-clear-btn" attribute you seem to be using jQuery Mobile. Yes they are validated as actual email format and number by the browser. And last but not least - mobile devices will often show different keyboard layout based on the input field type.

Comment: Aaaah, that's what makes them different. Yes I should've specified that I was using Jquery Mobile. Thank you very much. If you could turn that into an answer I'd like to accept it.

Comment: I only took the JQM hint because mobile experience is different, but the validation and semantics are true everywhere (with HTML5) as pointed out by answers below.

Comment: Alright. It was more that you just more directly answered my question. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not jQuery's but HTML5's. See [the doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.html) for more information.

Comment: Ah... that would be why JQuery didn't have much on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using HTML5 attributes which implementation depends on browsers.

See http://caniuse.com/ to check the implementation progress on browsers.

With some jQuery plugins you can emulate most of them.